# I am having a problem with opening two TouchGFX projects at once

Tags: stm32

I am working on a windows. I am trying to work on two projects at once. When I:
-generate code
-open the folder location
-locate touchGFX folder
-find ".project" and ".cproject"
I can't open neither of them. I could do that in the past.

Because I can't open the project directly from that location, I have to:
-open STM32CubeIDE
-click on "file"
-click on "open projects from file system"
and open the touchGFX generated code like that

So my problem is that I don't want to lose any code since I am trying to start a new project and the CudeIDE wont let me rename the project therefore I cant open 2 different projects at once.

I have tried renameing it directly in the TouchGFX folders but CubeIDE than wont let me open it

Comment: As far as I know, Cube imports all TouchGFX projects for the same MCU/Board with the same project name (at least it's how it happened to me, all TouchGFX imported projects in Cube were given name "STM32F746-Discovery" or something like that). Maybe try running two instances of CubeIDE with different workspaces to avoid project name clashing?